# How to use iron:router to create a separate link for each item in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm building a contacts app and I want to make it so that when a contact is selected it links to a page where it displays all the information for that particular person.

How would I go about implementing this? I was considering using a modal however this seems like the preferable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [iron router guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data) covers this and more:

```
<template name="Post">
  <h1>Post: {{title}}</h1>
</template>

Router.route('/post/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Post', {
    data: function () {
      return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    }
  });
});
```

If you are just starting with meteor though, you should consider [flow-router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router).

Start by reading the [Meteor Guide: Routing](http://meteor-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/routing/).

Comment: Should I be placing that Router.route code inside the event handler for when the contact is selected?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Handler with name 'post.:_id' already exists.
That's the error I'm receiving

Comment: no (not in the event handler), it's top level code for the client.  [Your options for client navigation are here](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#client-navigation).

Comment: So what? Everytime a new ID is added to the database there will be a new page created at the url .../post/id? Is that what this code does?

Comment: the route has a parameter (_id) in it.  That is how it generates a different page to display each different document in the database, while requiring just this one route, and one template.

Comment: I added a bit of code in my initial question if you could take a look at that and tell me what i'm doing wrong it would be very helpful thanks

Comment: `Router.go('/post/:_id');` needs to to change to `Router.go('/post/:' + VARIABLE_HOLDING_ID);`.  You will need to find out what that variable is, hopefully from the context (this) of your event handler.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The same button gets duplicated everytime a new contact is added so I believe I should be able to use this._id

Comment: It's now linking to each different id however it's still displaying all the contacts for some reason. It's obviously to do with the Post template I created however I can't see what exactly. It's also displaying them as the exact same way as how it does in the original page. This is weird because it seems like it's not even using the template as a reference considering I haven't told it to display the email yet like it does in the first page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93149/discussion-between-pablo-escobrah-and-jeremyk).

Comment: Sorry I can't chat now.  I suggest you go through the iron router guide, as this is all covered there.